# Get drop down list for search view in action bar

Tags: android, search, android-actionbar

Can you guys give me advice ? How can I edit this search view, to show me drop down list like in autoCompleteTextView ?? Need it for offer mathing items, next for onClick

```
 ...
 final MenuItem searchItem = menu.findItem(R.id.search);
 setupSearchView(searchItem);
 ...

 private void setupSearchView(MenuItem searchItem) {
 mSearchView = (SearchView) searchItem.getActionView();
 mSearchView.setQueryHint(getString(R.string.product_id));
 mSearchView.setQuery(mSearchQuery, false);
 mSearchView.setIconified(!mExpandSearch);
 final int searchIconResId = getResources().getIdentifier("android:id/search_button", null, null); 
 final ImageView searchIcon = (ImageView) mSearchView.findViewById(searchIconResId);
    searchIcon.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_action_search);  //
 ...
```

xml file

```
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
<item
    android:id="@+id/search"
    android:showAsAction="always"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_action_search"
    android:title="@string/search"
    android:actionViewClass="android.widget.SearchView" />

</menu>
```

Answer (score 1):

Instead of SearchView you can AutoCompleteTextView

```
<AutoCompleteTextView
        android:id="@+id/editText1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:ems="10"
        android:imeOptions="actionSearch"
        android:inputType="textAutoComplete|textAutoCorrect"
        android:textColor="#FFFFFF" >

        <requestFocus />
    </AutoCompleteTextView>
```

**And in Activity**

```
 ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,
            android.R.layout.simple_dropdown_item_1line, autocompletelistvalues);
    AutoCompleteTextView textView = (AutoCompleteTextView) v
            .findViewById(R.id.editText1);
    textView.setAdapter(adapter);
```

**include this to filter Dynamically**

```
 textView.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {

        public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, ....){
            //update your List based on CharSequnce entered  
        textView.setAdapter(filteredadapter);
         notifyDataSetChanged();
        }
    });
```

Comment: Hmm, but I need laaunch request depedns on what you start typing and after that, show some options

Comment: this will work for you i guess,ive Updated it to Dynamically change based on the Text you enter